# How to resolve unable to find lapho-mqtt3c for the given compiler command?

Tags: c, cross-compiling

I need to run the MQTTClient_publish.c against the arm-none-linux-gcc and for the same I have followed the below commands to build and install,

```
$ cmake -Bbuild -H. -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=OFF -DPAHO_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- CMake version: 3.10.2
-- CMake system name: Linux
-- Timestamp is 2020-04-20T06:39:20Z
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:    
    CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER

-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/build
```

Then I have installed it using, and all the samples are in /usr/local/samples and headers are in /usr/local/include and libraries are in /usr/local/bin

```
$ sudo cmake --build build/ --target install
Scanning dependencies of target common_obj
[  3%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTProtocolClient.c.o
[  7%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Clients.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/utf-8.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/StackTrace.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTPacket.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTPacketOut.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Messages.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Tree.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Socket.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Log.c.o
[ 39%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTPersistence.c.o
[ 42%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Thread.c.o
[ 46%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTProtocolOut.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTPersistenceDefault.c.o
[ 53%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/SocketBuffer.c.o
[ 57%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Heap.c.o
[ 60%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/LinkedList.c.o
[ 64%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTProperties.c.o
[ 67%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/MQTTReasonCodes.c.o
[ 71%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/Base64.c.o
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/SHA1.c.o
[ 78%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/common_obj.dir/WebSocket.c.o
[ 78%] Built target common_obj
Scanning dependencies of target paho-mqtt3a
[ 82%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/paho-mqtt3a.dir/MQTTAsync.c.o
[ 85%] Linking C shared library libpaho-mqtt3a.so
[ 85%] Built target paho-mqtt3a
Scanning dependencies of target paho-mqtt3c
[ 89%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/paho-mqtt3c.dir/MQTTClient.c.o
[ 92%] Linking C shared library libpaho-mqtt3c.so
[ 92%] Built target paho-mqtt3c
Scanning dependencies of target MQTTVersion
[ 96%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/MQTTVersion.dir/MQTTVersion.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable MQTTVersion
[100%] Built target MQTTVersion
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/MQTTAsync_publish.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/MQTTAsync_subscribe.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/MQTTClient_publish.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/MQTTClient_publish_async.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/MQTTClient_subscribe.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/paho_c_pub.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/paho_c_sub.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/paho_cs_pub.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/paho_cs_sub.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/samples/pubsub_opts.c
-- Installing: /usr/local/./CONTRIBUTING.md
-- Installing: /usr/local/./epl-v10
-- Installing: /usr/local/./edl-v10
-- Installing: /usr/local/./README.md
-- Installing: /usr/local/./notice.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.3.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.3.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/MQTTVersion
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/MQTTVersion" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MQTTAsync.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MQTTClient.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MQTTClientPersistence.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MQTTProperties.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MQTTReasonCodes.h
```

Now, when I compile the file

```
    user@user-VirtualBox:~/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/src/samples$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o pub MQTTClient_publish.c -lpaho-mqtt3c -I/usr/local/include
    cc1: warning: include location "/usr/local/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]
    /home/

user/octane_etk-6.0.0.240/arm-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpaho-mqtt3c
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to resolve this? am I missing any step here to link the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc against paho mqtt c?

Comment: Perhaps the most obvious thing to try first: did you tell gcc where to look for libraries with `-L/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: As an aside: I don't think you are using your cross-compiler correctly. Did your cross-compiler come with a [CMake toolchain file](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-toolchain)? If so, you should prefer that. Otherwise you need to use sysroots to make sure you only compile using headers from the cross-compiler. And never install cross-compiled libraries into system paths. Either install them under a separate directory, or put the libraries under architecture-specific paths (`/usr/local/lib/arm-none-linux-gnueabi`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266452/cannot-find-lpaho-mqtt3c-for-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g-compiler ? So my questinos still stand. So you compiled `paho-mqtt3c`, great, now the library will be somewhere in cmake build directory. Find it, add the path with `-L` (do not add `/usr/local/include` ever when cross compiling....) and link with the proper library.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah we tried installing in a separate directory and after that while compiling used -L/home/mindlogic/lib -lpaho-mqtt3c. But still we have been getting the same error.

Comment: No. Try `-L/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240/paho.mqtt.c/build/somwhere/here/where/libpaho-mqtt3c.so/is/`. `Install the project...` - it is a horrible idea to install cross-compiled library to your host OS. I suggest you remove it.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah pointing to that library. But still it says cannot find the library. We have linked the exact library as well.